# "Ich weiß nicht, wann der Zug abfährt" — Why is "der Zug" not accusative?

Tags: word-order, adverb, accusative

I understand "..der Zug abfährt" is an independent clause so it makes sense that it would have its own subject. I would just like to know the name of the rule/sentence structure that allows for/explains this so I can Google a long form explanation of it. Something about interrogative particles?

EDIT: The question is, how is it that both "ich" and "der Zug" are both the subject of this sentence

Comment: Yes, it‘s the subject, and the subject is always in nominative case, never accusative. What’s your question exactly?

Comment: @chirlu How are "ich" and "der Zug" both the subject? What are the rules for sentences having more than 1 subject?

Comment: It’s two sentences, one main clause (_ich weiß nicht_) and one subordinate clause (_wann der Zug abfährt_), each having their own verb and their own subject.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, the idea is to have different questions for, well, different questions. I therefore removed the “random add-on question”. You can find more about how Stack Exchange works in the [help].

Comment: @chirlu Ok, thanks that answers my question(If you post it as an answer I will mark it as such). I was operating under an 'ends in ./?/!' definition of a sentence.

Comment: I added an answer. Note that it‘s exactly the same in English, too: _I don’t know what he has done_ – if a complex sentence could only have one subject, either _I_ would need to turn into _me_, or _he_ into _him_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence consists of two clauses, one main clause (*ich weiß nicht*) and one subordinate clause (*wann der Zug abfährt*), each having their own verb and their own subject. Complex sentences can consist of many clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Here there are two clauses. The main clause is:

> Ich weiß nicht

and the subordinate clause is:

> wann der Zug abfährt.

In first clause, *Ich* is the subject. The second clause is an altogether different sentence with its own subject. The subject of main clause is related with the action *to know* and the subordinate clause has has the subject *der Zug,* which is associated with action *abfahren.* What the person doesn’t know is not *der Zug.* What he doesn’t know is *when the train departs.*